# Why is Welsh-Powell algorithm better than the basic greedy algorithm for graph coloring?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am not able to find any reason that why Welsh-Powell algorithm works better than the basic greedy algorithm for graph coloring.

In Welsh-Powell algorithm, the only thing that differs from the basic greedy algorithm for graph coloring, is that it visits the vertices in decreasing order of degree. How does this help it in getting bette results?

[You can read about the basic greedy algorithm for graph coloring here.](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-coloring-set-2-greedy-algorithm/)

Comment: How do you define "better"?

Comment: It is a greedy algorithm and won't always find the optimal solution (smallest number of colors). So better means more near the optimal answer. You can see an example and bit of explanation on this in the link.

Answer (score 9):

Note that Welsh-Powell is a special case of the basic greedy algorithm, all it does is to suggest a more specific order instead of an arbitrary order in which the vertices are visited. The idea is based on *heuristics* as follows: A new colour needs to be created in (any variant of) the greedy algorithm whenever the current vertex has all colours created so far among its already visitedneighbours. This unwanted situation can only occur for vertices of sufficiently high degree that are visited after sufficiently many of their neighbours. Hence if we try to visit all high-degree vertices before their neighbours, the "risk" of requiring a new colour should decrease.

Whether this is better **on average** is a tough question. However, the **worst case** of Greedy is $\max_v \deg(v)+1$ whereas for Welsh-Powell it is $\max_i \min\{\deg(v_i)+1,i\}$, which is strictly less in most cases.

Comment: And of course, if there are vertices whose degree is less than the chromatic number, there is obvious good reason to color them last. We will always be able to color them, so coloring them early will not help and can only do harm.

Comment: Isn't the worst case for greedy coloring the Grundy number of $G$, not $\Delta(G) + 1$?